# How can I make this SQL function that parses XML faster

Tags: sql-server, xml, umbraco, sqlxml

I am having a tough time finding a way to improve this custom SQL script to an Umbraco database.

Here is the sql script to get and parse the xml and select the correct value:

```
DECLARE @Title nvarchar(1000)
SET @Title =
(SELECT @NodeXml.query('//TechnicalData/title' ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') Title
FROM cmsContentXml xt JOIN umbracoNode un ON un.id = xt.NodeId
WHERE xt.nodeId = @NodeId)

SELECT iif(CHARINDEX('"values":null', @Title,0) > 0,'',Substring(@Title, 21, CHARINDEX('}', @Title) - 22)) Title
```

The partial XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TechnicalData id="1261" key="b6a2f67a-0f0f-40dd-a3c6-c5fb9d8b78b9" parentID="1092" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="12" createDate="2016-07-14T13:56:37" updateDate="2016-07-15T12:06:25" nodeName="Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden" urlName="rioolkolken-type-1-drainerend-via-de-zijwanden" path="-1,1089,1092,1261" isDoc="" nodeType="1154" creatorName="admin" writerName="Karl" writerID="1" template="1085" nodeTypeAlias="TechnicalData">
    <title>{"values":{"nl-BE":"Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden"},"dtdGuid":"f2dfa88e-63b9-4913-80cd-64d770cef90e"}</title>
</TechnicalData>
```

This is only one small part of the script. TechnicalData contains around 20 nodes, which all have to be parsed. The full script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/9SNSzWqm)

The reason for this custom script is because I needed to extend the Umbraco site with an ssrs report.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? The content of `title` is a JSON in SQL Server 2016 you could use `parseJSON`

Comment: I know but it is a 2012 installation. +1 for other people stumbling upon this Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is slow, because you take one single bit of information out of your XML over and over again.

With this you would get **all data typesafe** out of your XML in one sinlge go and without any string parsing.

```
DECLARE @NodeXml XML=
N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TechnicalData id="1261" key="b6a2f67a-0f0f-40dd-a3c6-c5fb9d8b78b9" parentID="1092" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="12" createDate="2016-07-14T13:56:37" updateDate="2016-07-15T12:06:25" 
nodeName="Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden" urlName="rioolkolken-type-1-drainerend-via-de-zijwanden" path="-1,1089,1092,1261" isDoc="" nodeType="1154" creatorName="admin" writerName="Karl" writerID="1" template="1085" nodeTypeAlias="TechnicalData">
    <title>{"values":{"nl-BE":"Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden"},"dtdGuid":"f2dfa88e-63b9-4913-80cd-64d770cef90e"}</title>
</TechnicalData>';

SELECT td.value('@id','int') AS id
      ,td.value('@key','uniqueidentifier') AS [key]
      ,td.value('@parentID','int') AS parentID
      ,td.value('@level','int') AS [level]
      ,td.value('@creatorID','int') AS creatorID
      ,td.value('@sortOrder','int') AS sortOrder
      ,td.value('@createDate','datetime') AS createDate
      ,td.value('@updateDate','datetime') AS updateDate
      ,td.value('@nodeName','nvarchar(max)') AS nodeName
      ,td.value('@urlName','nvarchar(max)') AS urlName
      ,td.value('@path','nvarchar(max)') AS [path]
      ,td.value('@isDoc','nvarchar(max)') AS isDoc
      ,td.value('@nodeType','int') AS nodeType
      ,td.value('@creatorName','nvarchar(max)') AS creatorName
      ,td.value('@writerName','nvarchar(max)') AS writerName
      ,td.value('@writerID','int') AS writerID
      ,td.value('@template','int') AS template
      ,td.value('@nodeTypeAlias','nvarchar(max)') AS nodeTypeAlias

      ,td.value('title[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Title

FROM @NodeXml.nodes('TechnicalData') AS A(td)
```

The result in this case was one single row with all your data in columns.

I doubt, that you need your values in declared variables, better use the above as CTE (**set-based / inline / ad-hoc** is in most cases better than **procedural**) and use the values from there. But: It was easy to fill the gathered information into declared variables as well (if really needed). In this case just declare your variables with correct types and use the syntax

```
SELECT @MyVariable=td.value('@id','int') 
      ,@OtherVariable= ...
... same for the rest...
```

Comment: This indeed speeded things up a bit. I also ended up putting the query in a stored procedure to bypass the need to create Query params for every declaration, as ssrs seems to automatically bind every declared var on top of the query as a query param...

Answer (score 1):

Parse all nodes in a single select

```
DECLARE @NodeXml xml;

-- sample data
SET @NodeXml ='<TechnicalData id="1261" key="b6a2f67a-0f0f-40dd-a3c6-c5fb9d8b78b9" parentID="1092" level="3" creatorID="0" sortOrder="12" createDate="2016-07-14T13:56:37" updateDate="2016-07-15T12:06:25" nodeName="Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden" urlName="rioolkolken-type-1-drainerend-via-de-zijwanden" path="-1,1089,1092,1261" isDoc="" nodeType="1154" creatorName="admin" writerName="Karl" writerID="1" template="1085" nodeTypeAlias="TechnicalData">
    <title>{"values":{"nl-BE":"Rioolkolken Type 1 Drainerend via de zijwanden"},"dtdGuid":"f2dfa88e-63b9-4913-80cd-64d770cef90e"}</title>
</TechnicalData>';

DECLARE @Title nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @Subtitle nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @Company int;
DECLARE @Date Datetime;

SELECT @Date = @NodeXml.value('(/TechnicalData/@createDate)[1]', 'datetime')
 ,@Title = td.node.value('title[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 ,@Subtitle = td.node.value('subtitle[1]','nvarchar(max)')
 ,@Company = td.node.value('bedrijf[1]','int')
 -- and so on
FROM  @NodeXml.nodes('TechnicalData') td(node);

--check it
SELECT @Date,@Title,@Subtitle,@Company ;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but Snugo's was more elaborate. +1 though